# Is there a reason why this happened in Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, when Gamora is explaining what Thanos intends to do with the Infinity Stones,

> **Gamora**: The entire time I knew Thanos, he only ever had one goal: To
>   bring balance to the Universe by wiping out half of all life. He used
>   to kill people planet by planet, massacre by massacre.
>
> **Drax**: Including my own.
>
> **Gamora**: If he gets all six Infinity Stones, he can do it with the snap
>   of his fingers, like this. [*She snaps her fingers.*] 
>    <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War* (2018)</sub>

Later, when Thanos arrives at Titan,

> **Doctor Stephen Strange**: Who wants to murder trillions.
>
> **Thanos**: With all six stones, I could simply snap my fingers, and they
>   would all cease to exist. I call that... mercy. 
>    <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War* (2018)</sub>

Both instances indicating that the "*Snap*" is intended for living beings only. However, in *Avengers: Endgame*, we see that

> when Tony snaps, the cavalry like the **Chitauri ships** and **Outriders' ships** etc. are dusted as well. 
>  
>  [image: Screenshots showing ships before unsnap - no ships after unsnap]
>   <sub>*Avengers: Endgame* (2019)</sub>

Have the writers given any explanation on this?

Comment: For the record, with the power of the stones you can do ***anything***. That's not limited to just killing living beings, it's limited to doing **absolutely anything you want,** which presumably boiled down to 'dust everything associated with Thanos' army'.

Comment: What Valorum said ^. Thanos wanted to "snap" 1/2 of all life in the universe away, but that's just what *he* wanted to do. He could've just as easily "snapped" the galaxy bigger and let life spread between more planets or something else, but opted for his solution. No reason why space-army-dusting couldn't be done, and it does make damage cleanup easier.

Comment: @Valorum I agree with both of you. I’m just looking if there’s anything specified. I mean in both of the movies they only talk about the snap dusting only living beings right?

Comment: @Shreedhar: “I mean in both of the movies they only talk about the snap dusting only living beings right?” — Thanos, before the final battle, says that because wiping out half of all life clearly didn't teach the universe the right lesson, he's going to rebuild the entire universe scratch this time. That's a bit more than dusting, and a bit more than living beings.

Comment: I've reopened this question since it wasn't a dupe of the one about chitauri ships, and re-closed it as a dupe of something which is actually asking the same thing. (Thanks to a flagger for bringing the poor dupe situation to mod attention.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor can't we merge the two because what I meant to ask here is the same as asked in the other question? Just found this on meta that says we can merge them: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha/147651#147651

Comment: @Shreedhar Merging is a special tool to put all the answers to two questions in one place. But your question has no answers, so in this case there's not much point in merging.